# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan wifi VPN config

Tags: wireless, vpn, netplan

On my test-laptop I set up my netplan like this

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0f1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.178.30/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.178.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [103.86.96.100,103.86.99.100]
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.178.30/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.178.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [103.86.96.100,103.86.99.100]
     access-points:
       "Linksys":
         password: "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Does anyone know how to set up a VPN connection? [ in my case nordVPN ]
On GUI mode, when netplan in set `renderer: NetworkManager` VPN works fine and all DNS leak test are ok.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: didn't find any useful guide to create on netplan. And don't know how to create any script to make it run on boot to work =(

Answer (score 1):

On desktop environments, using wireless connections, or using VPN, I'd recommend staying with NetworkManager.

VPN connection scripts can be automatically launched at connection time by using `nm-connection-editor`.

[image]
The `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # make config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot, and check operation

Comment: How to run VPN on GUI I can do with NetworkManager. CLI can't figure it out with networkd [ .yaml ]

Comment: @dMatija yes, on NM it's easy, and that's why I recommend you use it instead of netplan (until ANY documentation comes out to show us how to use VPN with it). And using nm-connection-editor you can make any profile auto-connect.